# ¿Cómo puedo verificar si un numero ingresado es igual a un numero en una lista en python?

Tags: python, lista, input

estoy intentando que el usuario digite un numero y verificar si ese numero está en una lista ya predeterminada
Este sería mi código

```
def Verificar():
  lista=[11,24,35,42,56]
  Numero=(input("Ingrese un numero :"))
  if Numero in lista:
    print("El numero pertenece a la lista")
```

Este codigo no imprime nada como salida

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta tarea la podemos realizar con un ciclo `for` que itere sobre todos los elementos de la lista, con un condicional validamos si el elemento está en la lista o no.

Adjunto lo dicho en código para que te quede más claro:

**Solución:**

```
def Verificar():
    lista = [11,24,35,42,56]

    Numero = int(input("Ingrese un número :"))

    for i in range(len(lista)):
        if Numero == lista[i]:
            print("El número pertenece a la lista")
            break
        else:
            print("El número no pertenece a la lista")
            break
```

Como puedes ver se pone un `break`, para que apenas llegue a una conclusión (si lo encontró o no) nada más haga el `print()` una sola vez. De lo contrario tendríamos muchas salidas por pantalla (no deseadas)

Ahora veamos unos ejemplos:

**Ejemplo uno:**

Como siempre invocamos la función, para ver resultados:

```
Verificar()
```

Salida por pantalla:

```
Ingrese un número :11
El número pertenece a la lista
```

**Ejemplo dos:**

```
Ingrese un número :89
El número no pertenece a la lista
```

Obtenemos dos salidas por pantalla diferentes, dependiendo si el elemento está en la lista o no

Espero haberte ayudado, saludos.

Answer (score 1):

De hecho el problema en este caso esta en la comparación, debido a los tipos de datos, tienes una lista de int, mientras que la función input() regresa un string, lo unico que necesitas hacer es convertir la salida en el tipo de datos que requieres, en este caso int:

```
def Verificar():
  lista=[11,24,35,42,56]
  Numero=int(input("Ingrese un numero :"))
  if Numero in lista:
    print("El numero pertenece a la lista")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def Verificar():
    lista = [11,24,35,42,56]

    Numero = int(input("Ingrese un número :"))

    for i in range(len(lista)):
        if Numero == lista[i]:
            print("El número pertenece a la lista")
            break
        else:
            print("El número no pertenece a la lista")
            break
```

Comment: Hola david, bienvenido y gracias por colaborar,  tu respuesta no es del todo correcta, si, por ejemplo, ingresas el número "24", te dirá que no pertenece, ya que al comprobar el "11", entra en el "else" e imprime el mensaje, para que sea correcta, debes quitar el "else" y poner el "print" correspondiente fuera del "for", te sugiero que edites tu respuesta y la corrijas a fin de evitar votos negativos.